# Using a dataset of filenames, create a dataset of images to tuples

Tags: python, tensorflow

I create a tensorflow dataset of filenames of many images in a folder. The images are named [index].jpg, where index is some integer used to identify the images. I have a dictionary of string 'index' to labels as tuples. How, using tf.data.Dataset.map, can I map the index to a label tuple?

Here's the map_func I am trying to pass to the map function:

```py
def grabImages(filepath):
   index = getIndexFromFilePath(filepath)
   img = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
   img = translateImage(img)
   dictionary = getLabelDictionary()
   return index, img
```

Where dictionary is the index to labels dict, index is the index of the filepath as tf.Tensor and img is a preprocessed image that was at the filepath.

This returns a dataset with the index, as a tensor, mapped to the corresponding image. Is there a way to get the labels of the `index` using `dictionary` using something like `dictionary[index]`? Basically, I want to find the string content of index.

I have tried using `.numpy()` and `.eval()` with the current session within the `grabImages` function, but neither work.

Comment: Can you provide an example output scenario desired? As this is quite confusing to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get string part of a tensor in the `tf.data.Dataset.map` function.

Below are the steps I have implemented in the code to achieve this.

1. You have to decorate the map function with `tf.py_function(get_path, [x], [tf.string])`. You can find more about tf.py_function [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function).
2. You can get your string part by using `bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())` in map function.

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def get_path(file_path):
    print("file_path: ",bytes.decode(file_path.numpy()),type(bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())))
    return file_path

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.jpg')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(get_path, [x], [tf.string]))

for one_element in train_dataset:
    print(one_element)
```

Output -

```
file_path:  /content/bird.jpg <class 'str'>
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/content/bird.jpg'>,)
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Andrew Wiedenmann - Please upvote and accept the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.